# php- $_POST method does not work

Tags: php, html, post, input, user-input

Code:

```
<html>
    <body>
    Username: <input type='text' placeholder='Username' name='user' id='user' value='Nytrix'></input><br>
    Password: <input type='password' placeholder='Password'  name='pass'></input><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Login' name='submit'> </input><br><br>
    <?php
        echo $_POST['user'];
    ?>
</body>
</html>

Error: Undefined index: user<br>
```

It doesn't matter how i try to get the value from an input in will never get it. So my question is what am i doing wrong or why does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `$_POST` to exist, the current page must have *posted*. You don't post any data to this page. A way to achieve this is to add a form to your page, in which you can add your elements and submit button.

example (w3schools)

```
<form name="input" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

ps: the input elements don't admin closing tags.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
echo $_POST['user'];
}
else
{
?>
<form  name="loginForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
 Username: <input type='text' placeholder='Username' name='user' id='user' value='Nytrix'></input><br>
    Password: <input type='password' placeholder='Password'  name='pass'></input><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Login' name='submit'> </input><br><br>
             <?php

}
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the form in order to have access to data inside `$_POST` . In your example you are accessing `$_POST` content without making sure there is a for submission. Once you click the submit button, the `$_POST` code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <?php
 if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {   
    echo $_POST['user'];
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `<form action="" method="post"> ... Inputs ... </form>`. Then you have a form to submit.